# Method with Object argument won't accept anything other than an Object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, parameters

We have a VB.net function with the following signature in class InitializerFactory:

```
Public Shared Function Create(ByRef ui As Object) As IModeInitializer
```

I'm attempting to test this function by passing in a mock of ui (using Rhino Mocks):

```
MainForm ui = mocks.StrictMock<MainForm>();
IModeInitializer item = InitializerFactory.Create(ref ui);
```

When attempting to pass ui as a parameter, I get the following errors:

- The best overloaded method match for 
  'InitializerFactory.Create(ref object)' has some invalid arguments
- Argument '1': cannot convert from 'ref MainForm' to 'ref object'

Ideally, the solution would be to extract an interface on UI (or its class, MainForm) but that's not doable by any means - it's an extremely bloated class.

I also can't declare ui as an `Object`, or else I can't mock the methods inside of it since the methods don't belong to an `Object` type.

My question is -- what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just because of the ref parameter syntax.  The problem is that the function has to be able to set ANY type of object, since it's a by ref parameter.  You can't just pass it a reference to a MainForm, which is what you're attempting.

Unfortunately, this is a pretty difficult API to work with.

You can handle this by assigning your instance to an object first:

```
MainForm ui = mocks.StrictMock<MainForm>();
object uiObj = ui;
IModeInitializer item = InitializerFactory.Create(ref uiObj);
if (uiObj != ui) { 
    // Handle the case where the reference changed!
    ui = uiObj as MainForm; // May be null, if it's no longer a "MainForm"
}
```

If you want to fully understand this, you can read up on [Covariance and Contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: I've tried this, but then I get the following error in NUnit:
**System.InvalidOperationException : The object '' is not a mocked object.** I'm assuming that it's talking about the uiObj since it's not just an Object as opposed to a mock object.

Comment: It would really help if you'd say where that error occurred. But I agree with Reed - it sounds like a horrible API. Does it really have to have a by-ref parameter?

Comment: @MunkiPhD:  That's not the problem.  Casting and assigning to object doesn't change the actual type of object.  You have some other issue going on inside of the method.

Comment: Yea, the API isn't the greatest in some areas, but 'it is what it is.'